# how do I use futures for parsing rss?

Tags: python, rss

I am new to python...you are warned.

I copied an example from http://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries but I keep getting the error

```
"future_calls = [Future(feedparser.parse,rss_url) for rss_url in hit_list]
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)"
```

Here is my code:

```
import feedparser
from futures import Future


hit_list = [ "http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture", "http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/healthNews" ] # list of feeds to pull down

# pull down all feeds
future_calls = [Future(feedparser.parse,rss_url) for rss_url in hit_list]
# block until they are all in
feeds = [future_obj() for future_obj in future_calls]

entries = []
for feed in feeds:
    entries.extend( feed[ "item" ] )
    sorted_entries = sorted(entries, key=lambda entry: entry["title"])
    print sorted_entries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using the right modules? You have:

```
from futures import Future
```

but if you mean to use the module from the [RssLibraries](http://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries) page you linked to, then it should be

```
from future import Future
```

(and you'll need to download the `future` module from the link on that page).

It looks like you're actually using the [futures module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) which is a back port of the Python 3 [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) module for earlier version of Python.

Comment: you're right. I just corrected it and am now getting stuck on another part...rather than do it here I will ask another question. thx